# Importing to Couch-DB changes encoding

Tags: json, node.js, couchdb

I have a database I am using that has support for different languages, the issue I am running into is, in the source SQL data, the format is correct.

```
MariaDB [stmtransit]> SELECT * FROM routes WHERE route_id = 181;
+----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+-------------+------------------+
| route_id | agency_id | route_short_name | route_long_name  | route_desc | route_type | route_url                                | route_color | route_text_color |
+----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+-------------+------------------+
|      181 |         1 | 369              | Côte-des-Neiges | NULL       |          3 | http://www.stm.info/fr/infos/reseaux/bus | 009EE0      | NULL             |
+----------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------------------------------+-------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I move do the query and move it into CouchDB, it changes accents and anything other than plain characters to

```
CÃ´te-des-Neiges
```

My request is

```
function queryRouteTable(db, route_id) {
return db.query({
    sql: "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE route_id = ?;",
    values: [route_id],
})
.take(1);
}
```

Then my upload to couch uses rx and rx-couch with the code, and no matter where I view the document.route_long_name after the initial grab, its always formatted wrong.

What am I missing, why does it change after initial grab.

Comment: It looks like your origin data isn’t in UTF-8. Is that possible?

Comment: @JanLehnardt it is, I've changed it from UTF8 and even tried UTF8MB4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out MariaDB has a bug which turns the database formating to latin1 intead of utf8

To correct for this you must go to /etc/my.cnf 
remove all instances of

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

find title "mysqld" in my.cnf and put under it

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

and save.

Then restart mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

To display the current character encoding set for a particular database, type the following command at the mysql> prompt. Replace DBNAME with the database name:

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "DBNAME";
```

If you have your encoding set per table use the following command. Replace DBNAME with the database name, and TABLENAME with the name of the table:

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation AND T.table_schema = "DBNAME" AND T.table_name = "TABLENAME";
```

**IMPORTANT: BACKUP YOUR DATABASE**

If you have a working backup of your database you can convert it from your current encoding to UTF-8 by issuing the following commands:

```
mysql --database=DBNAME -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" | awk '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}' | mysql --database=DBNAME
```

And in prompt:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Now you should be able to export using UTF-8 and import into couch using UTF-8 encoding...

Hope that helps...